# jquery mobile alternate button theme for dynamically populated buttons?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to display jquery mobile alternate button's with different color. The code which I am using now is only able to change the button theme to 'e' but I want 'theme b'.  What can be the problem? Below is the code.

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function(e) {
    var db = openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT id FROM DEMO", [],  

        function(tx, results) {

            var len = results.rows.length,
                i;
            //If no result Found
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var test = results.rows.item(i).id % 2; //to get the alternate row's
                if (test == 0) {
                    var id = "color" + results.rows.item(i).id;

                    $("#" + id).attr('data-content-theme', 'e').removeClass('ui-body-d').addClass('ui-body-e').trigger('create'); // Change to theme e
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am changing the button theme as per the id of dynamically populated buttons.

Comment: What have you tried? You say you want to set it to `b`, but your code shows you setting it to `e`

Comment: when i try to set it to `b` it resets it to `d`

Comment: How are you trying to set it to `b`? In the code above, at no point are you trying to set it to `b`. How have you been trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some HTML code it would help a lot.

You could try the following to see whether it solves the issue:

> $("#" + id).attr('data-content-theme', 'b').removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e').addClass('ui-body-b').trigger('create');

Comment: I am populating the button list using append statement using database id since users can be a bit prone to click on some other button I needed it to be colored alternately so I worked on the above code but its only working with theme `e` if I change it with any other theme it goes back to the default theme `d`.